# How do we query reverse foreign key attributes in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

We are using Django 1.4.12 with PostgreSQL to build a website for hotels. We have hotels, for each hotel we have rooms and in each room we have guests (a guest has a foreign key to a room, and a room to a hotel). After a guest checks out from a room, his `departure_date` is set to now, and if he is in the room, it is none. I want to select the rooms which have guests and the rooms which don't have guests, but I can't use "`guests__isnull`" because the guests remain connected to the room after they check out. I also need to search rooms when the guests' name contain a keyword, but only if they are in the room. If there is at least one guest in the room with a matching name, I want the room to be selected. But if this guest checked out, the room can't be selected.

Until a few days ago we removed the room of the guests after they checked out, but we need to keep it to save history. Our code was something like this:

```
hotel.rooms.filter(
    Q(description__icontains=keyword) | 
    Q(identifier__icontains=keyword) | 
    (Q(guests__isnull=False) & Q(guests__name__icontains=keyword))
).distinct()
```

and for checked in rooms we added `.exclude(guests__isnull=True)`. But now we keep the room and we need to check if the `departure_date` is null or not. How do we do it now? Remember that we need to match the keyword with guests that are in the room, but not with guests that are not in the room. We also need to count the total number of rooms with guests and the total number of rooms without guests.

**Update**: I tried to count the number of rooms with guests with the following query:

```
hotel.rooms.filter(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True).count()
```

But it returns an incorrect number (14 instead of 10). Do you know how to fix the query?

By the way, this query returns the correct number of rooms without guests (9 rooms):

```
hotel.rooms.exclude(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True).count()
```

Why is the exclude correct and the filter is not correct?

Comment: how about just having `guests__departuredate__isnull=True` - gives you the guests currently in the room

Comment: see the doc as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#s-lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Side note: if your `Guest` model has a relationship with your `Room` model, you're doing data modeling wrong. You should have a `Booking` (some name to that effect) model with a `room` field and the `Booking` model would include a foreign key to `Guest`, since a `Booking` is something that a guest has (potentially many of). Think about it; does a "guest" intrinsically have a "check-in date" or "check-out date"? What happens when they stay a second time again or book two adjacent rooms for the same night?

Comment: @orokusaki Thanks, but we don't need to keep check in and check out dates of previous visits if the guest checks in again. We are only interested in the last check in and check out dates. We also don't need to know previous rooms, only the current or last room of each guest. By the way, if the guest checks in again he might be registered with a different Guest object, if the reservation number is not the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. It appears that with filter(...), the rooms are duplicated per the number of guests in the room, but with exclude they are not. There are 2 possible solutions to count the number of rooms with guests:

```
hotel.rooms.filter(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True).distinct().count()
```

or:

```
hotel.rooms.exclude(~Q(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True)).distinct().count()
```

To count the number of rooms without guests:

```
hotel.rooms.exclude(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True).distinct().count()
```

or:

```
hotel.rooms.exclude(Q(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True)).distinct().count()
```

And to search rooms:

```
hotel.rooms.filter(
    Q(description__icontains=keyword) |
    Q(identifier__icontains=keyword) |
    Q(guests__isnull=False, guests__departure_date__isnull=True, guests__name__icontains=keyword)
).distinct()
```